# I need to Write OR statement within a string

Tags: java, string

I want to write if(myFunction.equals("This String OR This string")){
My code
}
Unable to implement the logic.

Comment: Do you mean comparing with two strings?

Comment: Look at the official java tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html for basic syntax

Comment: `if(myFunction.equals("This String") || myFunction.equals("This string"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that as you want it from our example. You have to do it like so:

`if(myFunction.equals(firstString) || myFunction.equals(secondString))`